# How to replace remapColums with remapColumnsByName in free jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Code from answer in [how to persist current row in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545953/how-to-persist-current-row-in-jqgrid)

is used to save jqgrid state. It saves jqgrid column state using column numbers. If jqgrid colmodel  is changed in server, this causes javascript error in browser.

[Freeze rownum column in JQGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820226/freeze-rownum-column-in-jqgrid) comment and https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README49.md describes method `remapColumnsByName` . I hoped that using this fixes the issUe.

free jqgrid was downloaded from todays git master. 
In state save after columns was resized or moved line

```
saveColumnState.call($grid, $grid[0].p.remapColumns);
```

was changed to

```
saveColumnState.call($grid, $grid[0].p.remapColumnsByName);
```

and in state restore in loadComplete code

```
    if (isColState && myColumnsState.permutation.length > 0 &&
                      myColumnsState.permutation.length === cm.length) {
        $grid.jqGrid("remapColumns", myColumnsState.permutation, true);

    }
```

with

```
    if (isColState && myColumnsState.permutation.length > 0 &&
                      myColumnsState.permutation.length === cm.length) {
        $grid.jqGrid("remapColumnsByName", myColumnsState.permutation, true);
    }
```

Now line

```
 if (isColState && myColumnsState.permutation.length > 0 &&
```

causes error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

How to fix this so that column state can  can used if column definition is changed?

Methods are defined as

```
var saveColumnState = function (perm) {
    var colModel = this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'),
        i, l = colModel.length, colItem, cmName,
        postData = this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData'),
        columnsState = {
            search: this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'search'),
            page: this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'page'),
            rowNum: this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'rowNum'),
            sortname: this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortname'),
            sortorder: this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortorder'),
            autoedit: autoedit,
            rownumbers: $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'rownumbers') && !$grid[0].p.colModel[0].hidden,

            searchWindow: searchParams,
            editWindow: editParams,
            permutation: perm,
            selectedRows: idsOfSelectedRows,
            colStates: {}
        },
        colStates = columnsState.colStates;

    if (typeof (postData.filters) !== 'undefined') {
        columnsState.filters = postData.filters;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        colItem = colModel[i];
        cmName = colItem.name;
        if (cmName !== 'rn' && cmName !== 'cb' && cmName !== 'subgrid') {
            colStates[cmName] = {
                width: colItem.width,
                hidden: colItem.hidden
            };
        }
    }
    saveObjectInLocalStorage(myColumnStateName, columnsState);
};

var saveObjectInLocalStorage = function (storageItemName, object) {
    if (typeof window.localStorage !== 'undefined') {
        window.localStorage.setItem(storageItemName, JSON.stringify(object));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I want to mention that the code described in the old answer works not always correct. To explain the problem you can open [the single row select demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_single.htm) for example and uses column chooser **multiple times** before reloading the grid. For example you can open column chooser first and change position of "Clients" column after "Tax" column. You will see correct results in the grid. Then you can open column chooser once more and move "Date" column after "Clients" column for example. You will see the columns in the order "Amount", "Tax", "Client", "Date", ... Now you can reload the page. You will see that the reloaded page have wrong order of columns: "Client", "Amount", "Tax", "Date", ... The reason on the problem: `permutation` used by column chooser or by `remapColumns` uses **integer position of columns relatively to current order of columns**. It makes saving of column order more complex. One have to hold **original** column order and recalculates always the values from `permutation` array to reordering of *original* `colModel`.

Alternatively one can saves *column names* instead of arrays with changed column position relatively to original column model. In other words one should replace `permutation` property of `columnsState` to something like `cmOrder` with array of column names in the grid, which choosed the user last time.

The method `remapColumnsByName` is very simple. It works like the method `remapColumns`, but its first parameter is array of column names instead of array of integer indexes.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_singleSelect.htm) is quick and dirty changing of the single row select demo to use `cmOrder` property instead of `permutation` property in `columnsState` and to use the method `remapColumnsByName` additionally. If you would repeat the same test like I described at the beginning of my answer you will see that new demo don't have the bug which I described before.

The most important parts of the demo which is different from original demo you will find below:

```
var getColumnNamesFromColModel = function () {
        var colModel = this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
        return $.map(colModel, function (cm, iCol) {
            // we remove "rn", "cb", "subgrid" columns to hold the column information 
            // independent from other jqGrid parameters
            return $.inArray(cm.name, ["rn", "cb", "subgrid"]) >= 0 ? null : cm.name;
        });
    },
    saveColumnState = function () {
        var p = this.jqGrid("getGridParam"), colModel = p.colModel, i, l = colModel.length, colItem, cmName,
            postData = p.postData,
            columnsState = {
                search: p.search,
                page: p.page,
                rowNum: p.rowNum,
                sortname: p.sortname,
                sortorder: p.sortorder,
                cmOrder: getColumnNamesFromColModel.call(this),
                selectedRows: idsOfSelectedRows,
                colStates: {}
            },
            colStates = columnsState.colStates;

        if (postData.filters !== undefined) {
            columnsState.filters = postData.filters;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            colItem = colModel[i];
            cmName = colItem.name;
            if (cmName !== "rn" && cmName !== "cb" && cmName !== "subgrid") {
                colStates[cmName] = {
                    width: colItem.width,
                    hidden: colItem.hidden
                };
            }
        }
        saveObjectInLocalStorage(myColumnStateName(this), columnsState);
    },
    ...
```

moreover the `loadComplete` callback which restore the order of the columns is the following

```
loadComplete: function () {
    var $this = $(this), p = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam"), i, count;

    if (firstLoad) {
        firstLoad = false;
        if (isColState && myColumnsState.cmOrder != null && myColumnsState.cmOrder.length > 0) {
            // We compares the values from myColumnsState.cmOrder array
            // with the current names of colModel and remove wrong names. It could be
            // required if the column model are changed and the values from the saved stated
            // not corresponds to the 
            var fixedOrder = $.map(myColumnsState.cmOrder, function (name) {
                    return p.iColByName[name] === undefined ? null : name;
                });
            $this.jqGrid("remapColumnsByName", fixedOrder, true);
        }
        if (typeof (this.ftoolbar) !== "boolean" || !this.ftoolbar) {
            // create toolbar if needed
            $this.jqGrid("filterToolbar",
                {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, defaultSearch: myDefaultSearch});
        }
    }
    refreshSerchingToolbar($this, myDefaultSearch);
    for (i = 0, count = idsOfSelectedRows.length; i < count; i++) {
        $this.jqGrid("setSelection", idsOfSelectedRows[i], false);
    }
    saveColumnState.call($this, this.p.remapColumns);
},
```

I want to repeat that the code from the new demo is far from be perfect. I just used the old code and fixed it to make it working in free jqGrid and by using new `remapColumnsByName` method.

Comment: Problem persists: sometimes line `if (isColState && myColumnsState.cmOrder !== null && myColumnsState.cmOrder.length > 0)` returns error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. Page remains in disabled state and cannot accessed. How to fix this, can this check improved ?

Comment: @Andrus: My code have `myColumnsState.cmOrder != null` instead of `myColumnsState.cmOrder !== null`. `!= null` is test for `null` or `undefined`. It's important!

Comment: jshint recommends to change this to `!==` so I changed it.  I fixed it by adding `&& typeof myColumnsState.cmOrder !== "undefined"` like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194381/how-to-use-native-date-picker-in-both-form-and-row-editing-in-free-jqgrid comment

Comment: @Andrus: There are many recommendations. For example jQuery style guide say the following (see [here](https://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/#equality)): "Strict equality checks (===) must be used in favor of abstract equality checks (==). The only exception is when checking for undefined and null by way of null." jqGrid code follow the rule. jshint can configuration parameter for the case.

Comment: I updated answer and added data corruption and application crash warnings

Comment: @Andrus: I absolutely disagree with you! My answer and the demo don't contains any data editing. Thus one can't speak about any data corruption! Before modifying the answer in such way you should first write new comment and not first edit and then inform me about it.

Comment: i am getting error as " Uncaught TypeError: $(...).remapColumnsByName is not a function" , And i am using jqGrid  4.4.4 version

Comment: @user3662273: remapColumnsByName method doesn't exist in version 4.4.4. It exists in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/) fork starting with version 4.9.0.