# How to achieve customize templates option in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I am having a grid whose configuration is placed in server for purely customizing sake where User can decide which columns he need to view and save the template.
Now if I want to have this feature present in grid whose configuration is also maintained in client side. How do I achieve it.

Pardon me if I m not clear or being a noob, I am still learning jqgrid .

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too common formulated. I would recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663268/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8547852/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935) which shows how the user could save the state of grid and to hide some columns, to change there width or order the columns. If I understand your question correctly, then the answers will provide you the main ideas for the implementation of your requirements. You can just try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_singleSelect.htm), make some changes in the grid and then close the demo and visit the demo once more. You will see that the hidden columns stay hidden, the order and the width of columns will stay persistent and so on.