# Persisting Row order and row width, free-jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Hi ive been trying to save the column order and width to a database per user. Ive acheived that it saves and loads the data back in correctly. However the grid does not change to reflect the colModel. Ive followed this awnser [Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641594/how-to-replace-remapcolums-with-remapcolumnsbyname-in-free-jqgrid/31663268#31663268) Everything appears to be working correctly the grid does simply not reflect the changed colModel. I get no errors and the data is saved and pulled out correctly so any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

After further investigation i changed the code to use local storage rather than the ajax calls and this works. So the issues is making the page wait for a response.

Ive included my code below. Firstly is the functions that where provided in the referenced answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641594/how-to-replace-remapcolums-with-remapcolumnsbyname-in-free-jqgrid/31663268#31663268).

```
var $grid = $("#ProjectTable"),
            cm = [
                {name: 'FieldProjectId', width: 10, align: 'center', key: true, search: false, hidden: true},
        {name: 'Edit', width: 30, search: false, sortable: false, align: 'center'},
        {name: 'Name', width: 100, index: 'Name', editable: true},
        {name: 'Code', width: 50, index: 'Code', editable: true},
        {name: 'Manager', width: 100, index: 'Manager', editable: true},
        {name: 'StartDate', width: 65, index: 'StartDate', search: true, formatter : 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'm/d/Y', newformat: 'd/m/Y'}, editable: true,editoptions : { dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker({
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        showWeek: true,
                        onSelect : function () { $('#ProjectTable')[0].triggerToolbar(); }
                    }).keyup(function(e) {
                        if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
                            $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
                        }
                    });
                }}, searchoptions: { dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker({
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        showWeek: true,
                        onSelect : function () { $('#ProjectTable')[0].triggerToolbar(); }
                    }).keyup(function(e) {
                        if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
                            $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
                        }
                    });
                } }},
        {name: 'CompletedDate', width: 65, index: 'CompletedDate', formatter : 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'm/d/Y', newformat: 'd/m/Y'}, editable: true, editoptions : { dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker({
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        showWeek: true,
                        onSelect : function () { $('#ProjectTable')[0].triggerToolbar(); }
                    }).keyup(function(e) {
                        if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
                            $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
                        }
                    });
                }}, sorttype:'date' , searchoptions: { dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker({
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        showWeek: true,
                        onSelect : function () { $('#ProjectTable')[0].triggerToolbar(); }
                    }).keyup(function(e) {
                        if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
                            $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
                        }
                    });
                }}},
        {name: 'Remark', width: 200, index: 'Remark', search: false, editable: true},
        {name: 'Status', width: 95, index: 'Status', editable: true },
        {name: 'Delete', width: 20, search: false, sortable: false, align: 'center'}
            ],
            saveObjectInLocalStorage = function (storageItemName, object) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%= Url.Action("SaveColumnStatePreference", "SampleSelection") %>',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { 
                        grid: storageItemName,
                        columnsState: JSON.stringify(object)
                    },
                    success:function(data) {
                    },
                    error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        console.log("Failed to save column state");
                    }
                });
            },
            getObjectFromLocalStorage = function (storageItemName) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%= Url.Action("GetColumnStatePreference", "SampleSelection") %>',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { 
                        grid: storageItemName
                    },
                    success:function(data) {
                        if(data !== undefined)
                        {
                            alert(data.colState);
                            return $.parseJSON(data.colState);
                        }
                    },
                    error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        console.log("Failed to recover column state");
                    }
                });
            },
            myColumnStateName = function (grid) {
                return window.location.pathname + "#" + grid[0].id;
            },
            idsOfSelectedRows = [],
            getColumnNamesFromColModel = function () {
                var colModel = this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
                return $.map(colModel, function (cm, iCol) {
                    // we remove "rn", "cb", "subgrid" columns to hold the column information 
                    // independent from other jqGrid parameters
                    return $.inArray(cm.name, ["rn", "cb", "subgrid"]) >= 0 ? null : cm.name;
                });
            },
            saveColumnState = function () {
                var p = this.jqGrid("getGridParam"), colModel = p.colModel, i, l = colModel.length, colItem, cmName,
                    postData = p.postData,
                    columnsState = {
                        search: p.search,
                        page: p.page,
                        rowNum: p.rowNum,
                        sortname: p.sortname,
                        sortorder: p.sortorder,
                        cmOrder: getColumnNamesFromColModel.call(this),
                        selectedRows: idsOfSelectedRows,
                        colStates: {}
                    },
                    colStates = columnsState.colStates;

                if (postData.filters !== undefined) {
                    columnsState.filters = postData.filters;
                }

                for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    colItem = colModel[i];
                    cmName = colItem.name;
                    if (cmName !== "rn" && cmName !== "cb" && cmName !== "subgrid") {
                        colStates[cmName] = {
                            width: colItem.width,
                            hidden: colItem.hidden
                        };
                    }
                }
                saveObjectInLocalStorage(myColumnStateName(this), columnsState);
            },
            myColumnsState,
            isColState,
            restoreColumnState = function (colModel) {
                var colItem, i, l = colModel.length, colStates, cmName,
                    columnsState = getObjectFromLocalStorage(myColumnStateName(this));

                if (columnsState) {
                    colStates = columnsState.colStates;
                    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                        colItem = colModel[i];
                        cmName = colItem.name;
                        if (cmName !== "rn" && cmName !== "cb" && cmName !== "subgrid") {
                            colModel[i] = $.extend(true, {}, colModel[i], colStates[cmName]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return columnsState;
            },
            updateIdsOfSelectedRows = function (id, isSelected) {
                var index = $.inArray(id, idsOfSelectedRows);
                if (!isSelected && index >= 0) {
                    idsOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1); // remove id from the list
                } else if (index < 0) {
                    idsOfSelectedRows.push(id);
                }
            },
            firstLoad = true;

        myColumnsState = restoreColumnState.call($grid, cm);
        isColState = myColumnsState !== undefined && myColumnsState !== null;
        idsOfSelectedRows = isColState && myColumnsState.selectedRows !== undefined ? myColumnsState.selectedRows : [];
```

And Secondly the Code for the jqGrid itself.

```
$('#ProjectTable').jqGrid({
            datatype: 'json',
            url: '<%= Url.Action("projectGridData", "SampleSelection") %>',
            mType: 'POST',
            colNames: [
            htmlDecode("<%=Atmis.EncodedLabel("Sample.Project.ProjectId", "ID") %>"),
            "",
             htmlDecode("<%=Atmis.EncodedLabel("Sample.Project.Name", "Name") %>"),
              htmlDecode("<%=Atmis.EncodedLabel("Sample.Project.Code", "Code") %>"),
               htmlDecode("<%=Atmis.EncodedLabel("Sample.Project.Manager", "Manager") %>"),
                  htmlDecode("<%=Atmis.EncodedLabel("Sample.Project.StartDate", "Start Date") %>"),
                   htmlDecode("<%=Atmis.EncodedLabel("Sample.Project.CompletionDate", "CompletionDate") %>"),
                   htmlDecode("<%=Atmis.EncodedLabel("Sample.Project.Remark", "Remark") %>"),
                   htmlDecode("<%=Atmis.EncodedLabel("Sample.Project.Status", "Status") %>"),
                   ""
                   ],
            colModel: cm,
            caption: htmlDecode("<%=Atmis.EncodedLabel("Sample.Project.Caption", "Project") %>"),
            width: $('#tabs-projects').width() - 20,
            sortname: 'FieldProjectId',
            loadui: 'block',
            rowNum: 20,
            rowList: [10,25,50,100,200],
            sortorder : 'desc',
            headertitles:true,
            ajaxGridOptions : {
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {



                    $('#ProjectTable').closest('.ui-jqgrid').block({
                        centerX: false, 
                        centerY: false,
                        message: $('#ProjectLoading'),
                        css: {
                            position: 'absolute',
                            padding: 0,
                            margin: 0,
                            width: 'auto',
                            top: '40%',
                            left: '45%',
                            textAlign: 'center',
                            cursor: 'wait' 
                        },
                        overlayCSS:  { 
                            backgroundColor: '#524f4f', 
                            opacity:         0.6, 
                            cursor:          'wait' 
                        } 
                    });
                },
                complete: function(xhr) {
                   $('#ProjectTable').closest('.ui-jqgrid').unblock();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   $('#ProjectTable').closest('.ui-jqgrid').unblock();
                }
            },
            resizeStop: function(width, index) { 
                 saveColumnState.call($grid, $grid[0].p.remapColumns);
            },
            sortable: {
                update: function(relativeColumnOrder){
                   saveColumnState.call($grid);
                }
            },
            height: 'auto',
            viewrecords: true,
            toolbar: [true, "top"],
            pager: $('#ProjectPager'),
            postData: {
                withLinks: true,
                clientId: function() {
                        return $('#ClientId').val();
                    }
            },
            editData: {
                clientId: function() {
                        return $('#ClientId').val();
                    }
            },
            beforeRequest: function () {
            },
            onclickSubmit: function (options, postData) {
                return {
                    ClientId: $('#ClientId').val()
                };
            },
            gridComplete: function () {
            },

            jsonReader:{
                    root: "rows",
                    page: "page",
                    total: "total",
                    records: "records",
                    repeatitems: false,
                    userdata: "userdata"
            },
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                // get data from the column 'userCode'
                var selRowId = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                var userCode = $(this).jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'FieldProjectId');


                SelectedProjectID = userCode;
                $('#tabs').tabs('enable', 1);
                $('#tabs').tabs('enable', 3);

            },
            loadComplete: function (data){

            var $this = $(this), p = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam"), i, count;

            if (firstLoad) {
                firstLoad = false;
                if (isColState && myColumnsState.cmOrder != null && myColumnsState.cmOrder.length > 0) {
                    // We compares the values from myColumnsState.cmOrder array
                    // with the current names of colModel and remove wrong names. It could be
                    // required if the column model are changed and the values from the saved stated
                    // not corresponds to the 
                    var fixedOrder = $.map(myColumnsState.cmOrder, function (name) {
                            return p.iColByName[name] === undefined ? null : name;
                        });
                    $this.jqGrid("remapColumnsByName", fixedOrder, true);
                }
            }
            saveColumnState.call($this, this.p.remapColumns);


            }
            }
            ).filterToolbar();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it' difficult to answer on questions with long code without having the possibility to debug it. Nevertheless I suppose that your problem is in the usage of `restoreColumnState` which you call in **synchronous way**: `myColumnsState = restoreColumnState.call($grid, cm);` in the code, but it calls `getObjectFromLocalStorage` which works **asynchronously**. The data `return $.parseJSON(data.colState);` returned from `success` callback of `jquery.ajax` will be just ignored. To fit the code you can rewrite the code to create the whole grid with the used state *inside of `success` callback*.

Comment: Hey yer it was a design pattern issue. I have six grids and each grid is based on the selection of the prior grid so i had to adjust the order in which i was getting the saved column state to ensure each grid was loaded and ready. After switching to the free jqGrid ive been able to simplify my code a great deal for example i don't have to write code to store arrays to persist selection across pages since that's now a feature. Thank you for your help again.