# Need to retain values on clicking "Back"

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, jqgrid

In mvc, assume I have a jqgrid or a form or any inputs in a page and I move to another page from that, then on clicking back, it needs to go back to that page retaining the previous selection or values. Any idea how to do this without using session objects?

Comment: no localstorage allowed as well.

Comment: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_singleSelect.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31663268/315935) and try to sort, to reorder the column, to hide some columns, to select the row and so on. After that you can gi to another page and to open the same URL once more. You will see the last state restored from the `localStorage`.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. #IRespect I have done more the same. but I am not allowed to use localstorage. I am looking for an approach based on mvc.

Comment: how about get variables ?