# free-jqgrid: easier way to save, load and apply filter data including filter-toolbar text and page-settings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have a pretty standard `jqGrid` using `free-jqGrid 4.13` with `loadonce: true;`

What I want to do is something I came across a couple of times:
 I want to save the state of the grid (without the data);
that means the settings (number of current page for example), filters the user applied and also the text in the filter-toolbar.
and then load and apply this data to the grid later.

jqGrid is such a powerful tool, but stuff like this seems such a pain to accomplish.

after hours and hours of work i came up with a complicated solution; it is working, but it's not a nice solution imho:

## 1) saving jqGrid filter-data (locally):

```
// in this example i am using the "window unload" event,
// because i want the filters to be saved once you leave the page:

$(window).on("unload", function(){

    // i have to access the colModel in order to get the names of my columns
    // which i need to get the values of the filter-toolbar textboxes later:
    var col_arr = $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");

    // my own array to save the toolbar data:
    var toolbar_search_array = [];
    for(var i = 0, max = col_arr.length; i < max; i++)
    {
        // only saving the data when colModel's "search" is set to true
        // and value of the filterToolbar textbox  got a length
        // the ID of the filterToolbar text-input is "gs_" + colModel.name
        if(col_arr[i].search && $("#gs_" + col_arr[i].name).val().length)
        {
             toolbar_search_array.push({ name: col_arr[i].name, value: $("#gs_" + col_arr[i].name).val() });
        }
    }

    // putting everything into one object
    var pref = {
        // 1. toolbar filter data - used to fill out the text-inputs accordingly
        toolbar :   toolbar_search_array,

        // 2. postData - contains data for the actual filtering 
        post :      $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData"),

        // 3. settings - this data is also included in postData - but doesn't get applied 
        // when using 'setGridParam'
        sortname:   $('#list').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortname'),
        sortorder:  $('#list').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortorder'),
        page:       $('#list').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'page'),
        rowNum:     $('#list').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'rowNum')

    };

    //saving in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("list",  JSON.stringify( pref ));
});
```

## 2) loading and applying jqGrid filter-data:

*for use in a document-ready closure, for example*

```
var localsave = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list"));

// these settings are also saved in postData, 
// but they don't get applied to the grid when setting the postData:
$('#list').jqGrid('setGridParam', {
    sortname: localsave.sortname,
    sortorder: localsave.sortorder,
    page: localsave.page,
    rowNum: localsave.rowNum
});

// this applies the filtering itself and reloads the grid. 
// it's important that you don't forget the "search : true" part:
$("#list").jqGrid("setGridParam", { 
    search : true,
    postData : localsave.post
}).trigger("reloadGrid");

// this is loading the text into the filterToolbar 
// from the array of objects i created:
console.log(localsave.toolbar);
for(i = 0, max = localsave.toolbar.length; i < max; i++)
{
    $("#gs_" + localsave.toolbar[i].name).val( localsave.toolbar[i].value );
}
```

it seems strange to me that `postData` contains all the data necessary but it's impossible to apply this data; at least as far as i know.

#### my question(s):

is it really this inconvenient to apply all the filter- and paging-data or am i missing something?
why can't this be as simple as:

```
// saving:
var my_save = $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData");

// loading:
$("#list").jqGrid("setGridParam", { 
    search : true,
    postData : my_save
}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

?

thank you for any help and/or suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663268/315935) with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_singleSelect.htm) provides an example of the implementation. The method `refreshSerchingToolbar` is relatively long. On the other side the code is still not full. It's not restore the state of operands, if the option `searchOperators: true` is used. I wanted to rewrite many parts of the `filterToolbar` method to make easier the saving/restoring of the the state of the filter toolbar or refreshing based on the changed `postData`. It's just the problem of the time and nothing more. What you describe is close to the feature `forceClientSorting: true`, which was difficult to implement in original code of jqGrid 4.7, but it was easy to implement after I rewrote large part of processing of the server response. The same problem is with the code of `filterToolbar`. The changes of `filterToolbar` is still in my TODO list and I'll made the corresponding changes soon.

Comment: thank you once again, oleg! good to know that there is no convenient solution at the moment, so i can quit searching and trying for now. and I am looking forward to your updated versions of `filterToolbar` and so on. In the meantime I'll stick to my workaround.

Comment: @low_rents: You are welcome! I understand that it would be better to represent the perfect solution, but one have to write the corresponding code before. Moreover, the more features has jqGrid the more time one need to implement new features because I want that the feature works in different combination of other option (frozen columns, `searchOperators: true`, different values of `guiStyle`, different `stype` and so on). Nevertheless I decided to write my answer to inform you about the current state of development and to provide the link to an old answer.