# jqGrid to reorder column by index name dynamically

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I want to reorder jqGrid columns by `column name` or by `column index (string)` not by `column index (int)`. I have seen this API

`$("#list").jqGrid("remapColumns", [0,1,12,3,14,5,6,7,8,11,2], true);`

It uses column index number but the problem is after altering the order jqGrid do a reindex and change the index. So i'm looking for the API which accept column name instead of integer value.

This is my code to get the column name

```
var columnModels = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
var user_visibalColumn = [];
for (var columnModelIndex in columnModels) {
    var columnModel = columnModels[columnModelIndex];
    if (!columnModel.hidden) {
        user_visibalColumn.push(columnModel.name);         
    }
}
//console.log(user_visibalColumn);
```

So after some time on an event I want to trigger `getGridParam` with the above `user_visibalColumn` array column.

Is this possible? If not then is there are way to add HTML data-tag col-id so that I can retrieve col-id.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/5019802) but I cannot able to figure out how to just implement `restoreColumnState`.

Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write allays which version of jqGrid you use (or can use) and from, which fork of jqGrid. Moreover it's important to write which fork of jqGrid you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Gurrido jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

I agree with the problem of the usage column indexes instead of column names. It's the reason why I made many changes in the free jqGrid fork, which I develop starting with making the main old fork commercial (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)) in the version 4.7.1. I introduced the method `remapColumnsByName` together with the old method `remapColumns`. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663268/315935) provides [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_singleSelect.htm), which demonstrates the usage of `remapColumnsByName`. Moreover free jqGrid holds mostly column names instead of column indexes internally and it has the helper  option `iColByName`, which helps to get the current index of the column by the column name.

I recommend you to upgrade jqGrid, which you use to the current (4.13.4) version of free jqGrid and to use `remapColumnsByName`.

Comment: I follow IST, so just going to bed (its 1AM here), if you don't mind can check you aswer in the morning? and Im using `jqGrid js version 5.1.1` its a free version.

Comment: @RaunakGupta: don't hurry. We can continue in the morning or next week. It's important to understand that 5.1.1 is **not free** at least for commercial usage even it the source is opened (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid)). It's Guriddo jqGrid JS. You can see the License on the first comment of the file. You have to pay the price, which you can find [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). You can examine the problem detailed by reading the license agreement and searching in internet about the subject.

Comment: thanks @Oleg for pointing out this, I did't knew about this, i'll downgrade my jqgrid library. btw I'm very much new in jqGrid in fact this is the first time i have used it, being a Laravel Developer I use `yajra datatables` package, which is use to solve all my purpose.

Comment: thanks `remapColumnsByName` is working with `jqGrid 4.13.5-pre`.